# Hotkey field in XUL for Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I have a Firefox extension written in XUL. It takes a hotkey. I want to have an input field where the user can press any key and I can programmatically determine what key was pressed.

I don't care about key combos which have meta meanings inside the OS (I don't need to capture Ctrl + Alt + Del).

If the key is already defined by Firefox, I'm OK with not capturing it (for instance, if the user presses F1 and help pops up instead of the key being captured, I'm fine).

I would also love to have some way to determine programmatically whether the key pressed already has some other meaning inside of Firefox, but that is likely out of scope for this request. I just mention it in case it's easy.

My current solution, which seems to have been adopted by a number of add-ons, is to provide a text box where the user can type a printable character and then a series of check boxes for modifier keys. This solution is barely workable but terrible for a number of reasons (it doesn't allow users to use non-printing keys such as function keys in their combos, it allows the user to input invalid characters (such as Unicode characters with no physical key on the keyboard), and it's just awkward to use).

Thanks!

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please *[edit] the question* to include your source code in the question. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Um...I appreciate the time you took to comment. I really do. But why are you asking me what code I've already tried? My question is whether there's a XUL component which will do what I want. I have not found such a component, so I have tried no code. I will update the question to describe my existing solution, which is very far from what I want.

Comment: I did this in the inline options page of my addon WorkspaceHopper: https://github.com/Noitidart/WorkspaceHopper and https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/workspacehopper/?src=api

Comment: @Notidart - Very nice! I'll have to see if I can use that same method for my extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Inline Options**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Inline_Options

You can detect the key pressed in the text input and write your modifiers like accel or alt.

[image: Inline Option]

Source example:
http://git.io/vez1o

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this won't actually detect a nonprinting key like F12, right? It's still just a normal text box.

Comment: Yes, you need write the code to change the value in the textbox the word F12.
You can test your keyboard here:
http://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html